# Multiprocessing not working/documentation not correct

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to get my program to run with the multiprocessing module but with no success so I reverted going back to the basics and tried simple examples from the documentation.  But even the simplest example does not work.  Here is the example I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))   
    p.start()
    print('Got here')
    p.join(5)
    print('finally')
```

This is straight out of the documentation with a few tweaks.  When I run it it prints 'Got here' and after 5 seconds it prints 'finally'.  It does not print 'hello Bob' and without the 5 second timeout is just goes to sleep after 'Got here' .

I am using IDLE with Python 3.6.4 on a Mac.  My actual program is more complicated than this but if I can't get this simple one working I am completely stuck.

Here is another non-working simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def print_process(number):
print('Printing from process ',number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_list = []
    for i in range(20):
        p = Process(target= print_process, args = (i,))
        process_list.append(p)
        print(i)

    for p in process_list:
        print('Starting')
        p.start()
```

It prints the numbers 0 to 19 and then prints 'Starting' twice before going to sleep.

Comment: But it does work? It prints `('hello', 'bob')`  because of your `print` method. If you print it as `print('hello ' + name)` it will be a normal string.

Comment: This works fine on 3.6.4 on Windows. Perhaps a buffer issue in IDLE. Try adding `flush=True` to your print statements.

Comment: Mark:  It doesn't print anything.  Bram: Flushing does not help.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't work on IDLE here either but it does work on PyCharm. Off-topic: for this and other reasons, I am not a fan of IDLE. There are better Python IDEs out there!

Comment: Yes it looks like it is IDLE.  They work with PyCharm